# How to remove all characters in a line beginning with a certain word in Notepad++

Tags: regex, search, find, notepad++

I have a very long list of Notepad++ search results from a “Find in files” search, and I just want to keep the actual file names found, and not all the hits in them.

The pattern in the search results is like this:

```
D:\XML\xml\cjpp-2012-0298.xml (45 hits)
Line 20: <mml:math><title id="ttl2-5">System <inline-formula id="ieq17">
Line 45: <title id="ttl2-8">System <inline-formula id="ieq17">
D:\XML\xml\cjm-2013-1234.xml (12 hits)
Line 45: <mml:math>....</mml:math>
```

...and so on.

Basically, I want to match and remove all lines that begin with `Line` so that I can isolate the file names. I have tried `^[Line].*?` and `^Line.*?`

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Remove the brackets: `^Line.*`

Comment: if you're using linux try `cat myFile.txt | grep Line`

Comment: As noted in my post, that is one of the things I tried. No soap.

Comment: Square brackets create a character set, so your first pattern will only match one of those characters. Your second pattern is failing because of the `?` at the end, which makes the `*` quantifier lazy (it will match as few times as possible).

Comment: If I do ^Line.* then everything after the first instance of "Line" is removed, including all the file names. I need this to remove each line individually, and then start looking for the next line beginning with "Line", skipping over any lines that don't start that way.

Comment: Sounds like you have single line mode enabled, which causes `.` to match newline.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: OK the problem was I had the match newline option turned on. Sorry....

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Line.*\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

---

- *check Wrap around*
- *Check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep -v '^Line' > outfile.txt
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)